# Want to programmatically set zoom on yworks GraphCanvasComponent with ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am using flex 3.6 and yworks version 2.8.

I am having trouble manually setting the zoom on a GraphCanvasComponent in my mxml actionscript code.  The zoom property is bound to a slider.  Here is an except of the binding:

```
    <yworks:GraphCanvasComponent
        id="graphCanvas"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        minZoom="0.25"
        maxZoom="8"
        mouseWheelZoomFactor="1.02">

   <mx:HSlider
        id="zoomSlider"
        width="150"
        showDataTip="false"
        change="{graphCanvas.zoom=Math.pow(2,event.value)}"
        liveDragging="true"
        tickInterval="1.0"
        value="{Math.log(graphCanvas.zoom)/Math.log(2)}"
        labels="{[graphCanvas.minZoom, graphCanvas.maxZoom]}"
        minimum="{Math.log(graphCanvas.minZoom)/Math.log(2)}"
        maximum="{Math.log(graphCanvas.maxZoom)/Math.log(2)}"/>
        <!-- the slider's minimum, maximum and value are bound
          to the corresponding properties on graphCanvas -->
```

However, when I manually set the zoom property on the GraphCanvasComponent in action script, it appears to get set but the actual graph does not zoom and the slider does not move to reflect the new value.

Here is my action script code.  It is a callback from a RoundtripHandler event in case that matters.

```
private function onNetworkTopologyUpdateComplete(
  event:RoundtripEvent):void
{
   graphCanvas.zoom = 4.0;
}
```

Please let me know how I can make a programmatic change to the zoom on my component.  Thanks!

Comment: What is "flex 3.6 for Java"?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the yworks engineers and they said that after the RoundtripHandler has finished it schedules a fitContent call. Since this will be executed asynchronously it will overwrite the zoom settings.

The solution is to the set fitContentOnUpdate property to false on the RoundtripHandler.  When you do this then the fitContent call does not happen.